# Submit form after receiving AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, submit, form-submit

I have a use case of sending form submission data to different server, before submitting the form to its action target.
So I need to delay form submission until I receive response given from AJAX request.

My limitation is that I can't use jQuery functions as I am developing my own library set for the product, which must be lite enough.

Now, I could have done something like unbind("submit") event on the form using jQuery, which could be called as callback in the AJAX function. But again, I've limited options.

My current form tracking code goes as:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
          event.preventDefault();            
          var url = "/lead/track/trackId/" + trackId;
          var data = {};
          for (var prop in fields) {
            data[prop] = document.getElementsByName(prop)[0].value;
          }
          data['planId'] = planId;
          data['visitorId'] = visitor_id;
          var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          http_request.onreadystatechange  = function(){
            if (http_request.readyState == 4  )
            {
                  setTimeout(function() {document.forms[0].submit();}, 0);
            }
          }
```

event.preventDefault() completely removes the submit action. If I remove this line, form goes to submission without waiting for AJAX response.
document.forms[0].submit() also doesn't helps. Its not receiving a form object, and displays "object is not a function". It could because this code is loaded asynchronously from a remote file.

Have already seen multiple jQuery alternatives. So, I need a specifically need a native Javascript based solution.
Thanks

Comment: Is `form` the same form as `document.forms[0]`?

Comment: There is a single form in the page and testing documents.forms[0] in console gives the correct form, but I would like to specify that this particular code is loaded asynchronously from a remote JS file.

Comment: My question is if the `form` in `form.onsubmit = function() {` is the same as `document.forms[0]`. If it is, which it sounds like, you can't simply use `event.preventDefault();`, because you're trying to manually submit it later (in the AJAX response handler). The dirty solution is to use a flag (boolean) outside the `onsubmit` handler. You'll set it to `true` in the AJAX response handler, so the submit handler knows that the AJAX has completed and the normal submit needs to happen, not the AJAX stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I am anyways trying to avoid preventDefault(). 
Let me check and revert with update. Thanks.

Comment: You need `preventDefault()` to stop the first form submission (so the AJAX request can succeed). But after that, you need the form to submit (don't execute the `preventDefault()`)

Comment: Although it's jQuery code, it can easily be converted, but here's what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/JJB3C/ . Again, it's dirty

Comment: Thanks, let me convert and post accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57054/discussion-between-utkarsh-mishra-and-ian).